# How to dispose the old font of a Button in swt java

Tags: java, fonts, swt

I'm trying to update a button's font at regular intervals, and this is how I implement it.

```
Font font = buttons.getFont();
FontData[] fontData = font.getFontData();
for(int j = 0; j < fontData.length; ++j) {
    fontData.setStyle(SWT.ITALIC | SWT.BOLD);
}
font = new Font(display, fontData);

buttons.setFont(font);
```

but doing this make the program crashed after some time with the exception

> org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
>     at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4387)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1258)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.internal_new_GC(Display.java:2673)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.computePoints(Device.java:241)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font.getFontData(Font.java:188)

My guess is that I've created many font objects without disposing  them in time. but I have no idea how to dispose them correctly, can anyone help me with it? if my guess is wrong, pls tell me what's the true reason of the `no handle` exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using getFont().dispose() and setFont() on button as,

```
final Font arialFont = new Font(Display.getCurrent(), "Arial", 40,
        SWT.NORMAL);
final Font courierFont = new Font(Display.getCurrent(), "Courier New",
        8, SWT.NORMAL);
final Button btn = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);
btn.setText("New Text");
btn.setSize(100, 30);
btn.setFont(arialFont);
Button changeBtn = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);
changeBtn.setText("Change Font");
changeBtn.setSize(100, 30);
changeBtn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
        count = count + 1;
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            btn.getFont().dispose();
            btn.setFont(arialFont);
        } else {
            btn.getFont().dispose();
            btn.setFont(courierFont);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: your code remind me that if I put these two fonts to the private member variables of the class, then I only create two fonts, I guess I don't need to dispose it since there are only two objects. is that right?

Comment: I guess, dispose is not required. You can try without dispose also.

Comment: @richard Please keep in mind, that although you only use two `Font`s, you will have to `dispose()` them eventually.